# How to install python database library to work with robotframework - API issue

Tags: python, database, api, robotframework

I am on a Windows 7 64bit machine, using Python 2.7 and I am trying to use the python database library in robotframework.  I have previously used a java library file but now I want to use the python library.

I have gone to [github](http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/) and [downloaded version 0.6](https://github.com/franz-see/Robotframework-Database-Library/archives/0.2).

I have also installed a setup file and MySQL-python from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)

However when I try to install the database library (using python `setup.py` build) I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    from DatabaseLibrary import __version__
  File "src\DatabaseLibrary\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from connection_manager import ConnectionManager
  File "src\DatabaseLibrary\connection_manager.py", line 16, in <module>
    from robot.api import logger
ImportError: No module named api
```

Why do I not have `robot.api` and how do I get it and install it?  Or is there an easier way to install the python database library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Database library uses Robot Framework internals, but does not list Robot Framework as it's dependency. The robot.api package was introduced in RF 2.6, so upgrading/installing the latest Robot Framework (from [project pages](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/downloads)) should resolve your issue

Comment: Thanks Janne, I went with another approach but your answer is the best approach. (unfortunately I need 15 points to give you a vote)

Answer (score 0):

First ensure the integrity of your module before trying to install. In order to install a module using distutils (setup.py) you need to run this command as an administrator:

```
python setup.py install
```

That should run the setup and report back to you any missing dependencies.

Alternatively, you can install PIP from this location: [PIP Project home page](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html). Their page provides instructions how to install PIP, it's a package manager for Python, similar to PEAR for PHP, CPAN for Perl or gem for ruby. When you have it installed you can install packages with this command:

```
pip install <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I did not have the "API" folder in the "Robot" folder in "Python27\Lib\site-packages" as I did not have the latest version of RF.  And logger is a new logging API for Robot Framework 2.6 since Oct 2011. (As janne as pointed out)

Two fixes for this issue seem to be:

1. Tested and worked but not recommended unless you dont want to update RF:  Edit the 2 files "connection_manager.py" and "query.py" in "robotframework-databaselibrary-0.6" so that there is no dependency on the Robotframework logger.  This is a easy and quick edit, where you replace the "from robot.api import logger" to "import logging" and "logger" to "logging"
   See "http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-logging-apis" for more detail.
2. Reinstall Robotframework and ensure the "API" folder is created.  This is recommended as it is the best approach.

(Added as an answer as too long for a comment)